# Vaadin Field.class interface extends Focusable.class and Component.class!! WHy?

Tags: vaadin

I puzzled Why Feild interface in Vaadin extends Focusable and component interfaces ??
since Focusable interface extends component itself ! Its enough for Field interface to extend focusable.
am i missing something here? is there any reason to this?

Can anyone help me out ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, there are no semantic reason for this. It might be a question of style, or it might be a historic reason for the class to explicitly extend an interface it already extends implicit.

Comment: i checked the source repository Foucusable.class, Field.class and Component.class no historic reason!! the classes were designed and developed this way!! <http://dev.vaadin.com/changeset/22317/svn/versions/6.7/src/com/vaadin/ui/Field.java>

Comment: http://dev.vaadin.com/changeset/22317/svn/versions/6.7/src/com/vaadin/ui/Field.java

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason anyway :)! As they change the code in next release of library, seems this was just a bug